# AJAX and PHP has problems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if this is a dumb question.  I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if there's possibly a better way to troubleshoot my problem.  I'm using AJAX to submit information to a php handler and then basically replace the data on my page with updated info so that the page doesn't have to refresh everytime.

This is my AJAX code.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#start<?php echo $rowCount; ?>").click(function(){
                        $("#displayJobs").load("assemblyStartHandlerCopy.php", {
                            jobID: <?php echo $jobID; ?>,
                            roomID: <?php echo $roomID; ?>,
                            finishColor: '<?php echo $finishColor; ?>',
                            startTime: '<?php echo $assemblyS; ?>'
                        });
                        $("#displayJobsNotStarted").load("assemblyNotStartedCount.php");
                    });
                });
</script>
```

And my PHP code is

```
<?php include "../../../includes/db.php"; ?>
<?php
    $startBtnColor = "";
    $completeBtnColor = "";
    $onQlistStatus = "On Q-List";
?>

<!--IF START BUTTON UPDATE DATA-->
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
if(isset($_POST['jobID'])) {
    $jobID = $_POST['jobID'];
    $roomID = $_POST['roomID'];
    $finishColor = $_POST['finishColor'];
    $startTime = $_POST['startTime'];
    $start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if($startTime == NULL || $startTime == 0) {
        $startTime = $start;
    }
    elseif($startTime != NULL || $startTime == 0) {
        $startTime = 0;
    };

$querySetStart = "UPDATE rooms SET assemblyS = '$startTime' WHERE jobID = $jobID AND finishColor = '$finishColor'";
$resultSetStart = mysqli_query($connect, $querySetStart);

if(!$resultSetStart) {
    echo "Start Button Failed " . mysqli_error($connect);
};
?>

<!--GET AND DISPLAY JOBS-->
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="rowStart">Start</th>
                <th class="rowJobName">Job Name</th>
                <th class="rowWoodType">Wood Type</th>
                <th class="rowFinishColor">Finish Color</th>
                <th class="rowComplete">Complete</th>
            </tr>
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT 
        jobs.jobID,
        jobs.jobName, 
        rooms.roomID, 
        rooms.roomName, 
        rooms.assemblyS,
        rooms.assemblyF,
        rooms.assemblyNeeded,
        rooms.woodType,
        rooms.finishType,
        rooms.finishColor
        FROM jobs 
        LEFT JOIN rooms 
        ON jobs.jobID = rooms.jobID 
        WHERE rooms.assemblyNeeded = 1 AND jobs.status = '$onQlistStatus' AND rooms.assemblyF IS NULL
        OR rooms.assemblyNeeded = 1 AND jobs.status = '$onQlistStatus' AND rooms.assemblyF = 0
        GROUP BY jobs.jobName, rooms.finishColor 
        ORDER BY deliveryDate, jobName, finishColor LIMIT 100";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $x = 1;
    $rowCount = 1;

    if ($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $jobID = $row['jobID'];
        $jobName = $row['jobName'];
        $woodType = $row['woodType'];
        $finishColor = $row['finishColor'];
        $roomID = $row['roomID'];
        $assemblyS = $row['assemblyS'];
        $assemblyF = $row['assemblyF'];
//SET BUTTON BACKGROUND COLOR
        if ($assemblyS != NULL) {
            $startBtnColor = "green";   
        };
        if ($assemblyS == NULL || $assemblyS == 0) {
            $startBtnColor = "white";
        };
//ALTERNATE ROW COLOR
        $x++;
        if ($x%2 == 0) {
            $class1 = "backgroundColor1";
        }
        else {
            $class1 = "backgroundColor2";
        };
//DISPLAY ROW INFORMATION
        $start = "<td class='rowStart'><button id='start$rowCount' style='background-color: $startBtnColor'>Start</button></td>";
        ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#start<?php echo $rowCount; ?>").click(function(){
                        $("#displayJobs").load("assemblyStartHandlerCopy.php", {
                            jobID: <?php echo $jobID; ?>,
                            roomID: <?php echo $roomID; ?>,
                            finishColor: '<?php echo $finishColor; ?>',
                            startTime: '<?php echo $assemblyS; ?>'
                        });
                        $("#displayJobsNotStarted").load("assemblyNotStartedCount.php");
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <?php
        $jobName = "<td class='$class1 rowJobName'>$jobName</td>";
        $woodType = "<td class='$class1 rowWoodType'>$woodType</td>";
        $finishColorRow = "<td class='$class1 rowFinishColor'>$finishColor</td>"; 

        $complete = "<td class='rowComplete'><button id='complete$rowCount' style='background-color: $completeBtnColor'>Complete</button></td>";
            ?>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#complete<?php echo $rowCount; ?>").click(function() {
                        $("#displayJobs").load("assemblyCompleteHandlerCopy.php", {
                            jobID: <?php echo $jobID; ?>,
                            roomID: <?php echo $roomID; ?>,
                            finishColor: '<?php echo $finishColor; ?>',
                            completeTime: '<?php echo $assemblyS; ?>'
                        }, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                            if(statusTxt == "success") {
                            //DO NOTHING    
                            };
                            if(statusTxt == "error") {
                                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                            };
                        });

                    $("#displayJobsNotStarted").load("assemblyNotStartedCount.php");
                    $("#recentlyCompleted").load("assemblyRecentlyCompletedHandler.php", {
                        complete: 1
                    }, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                            if(statusTxt == "success") {
                            //DO NOTHING    
                            };
                            if(statusTxt == "error") {
                                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                            };
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        echo "<tr>" . $start . $jobName . $woodType . $finishColorRow . $complete . "</tr>";
        $rowCount++;
    };
    };  
?>
            </table>
<?php
}
?>
```

I know it's pretty messy.  Basically all the information is being pulled into a table and echoing the rows out through a while loop.  Then if I select a button associated with a "job" or "row" it 1st marks a start time, 2nd changes the color, and 3rd gives me a new count.
Is there a better way to do this or a way to make sure my code won't fire unless it's a success.

The weird thing to me is that my code is duplicated in the PHP handler.  If I refresh the page everything is displayed correctly every time with no problems.

Comment: I would advise keeping them more separate, using AJAX to POST data to PHP and have PHP return JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested, I would create a standalone PHP script that can be used with AJAX. This might look like:

**PHP**

```
<?php 
include "../../../includes/db.php"; 
$startBtnColor = "";
$completeBtnColor = "";
$onQlistStatus = "On Q-List";

date_default_timezone_set("America/Denver");
if(isset($_POST['jobID'])) {
    $jobID = $_POST['jobID'];
    $roomID = $_POST['roomID'];
    $finishColor = $_POST['finishColor'];
    $startTime = $_POST['startTime'];
    $start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if($startTime == NULL || $startTime == 0) {
        $startTime = $start;
    } elseif($startTime != NULL || $startTime == 0) {
        $startTime = 0;
    }

    if($stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE rooms SET assemblyS = '?' WHERE jobID = ? AND finishColor = '?'")){
        $stmt->bind_param("sis", $startTime, $jobID, $finishColor);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            echo "Update Start Button Failed " . mysqli_error($connect);
            $connection->close();
            die();
        }
    }
    $connection->close();
    die();
}

$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT 
        jobs.jobID,
        jobs.jobName, 
        rooms.roomID, 
        rooms.roomName, 
        rooms.assemblyS,
        rooms.assemblyF,
        rooms.assemblyNeeded,
        rooms.woodType,
        rooms.finishType,
        rooms.finishColor
        FROM jobs 
        LEFT JOIN rooms 
        ON jobs.jobID = rooms.jobID 
        WHERE rooms.assemblyNeeded = 1 AND jobs.status = '?' AND rooms.assemblyF IS NULL
        OR rooms.assemblyNeeded = 1 AND jobs.status = '?' AND rooms.assemblyF = 0
        GROUP BY jobs.jobName, rooms.finishColor 
        ORDER BY deliveryDate, jobName, finishColor LIMIT 100");
if($query){
    $query->bind_param("ss",$onQlistStatus,$onQlistStatus);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($result);

    $x = 1;
    $rowCount = 1;
    $results = array();

    if ($result) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $results[] = array(
                'jobID' => $row['jobID'],
                'jobName' => $row['jobName'],
                'woodType' => $row['woodType'],
                'finishColor' => $row['finishColor'],
                'roomID' => $row['roomID'],
                'assemblyS' => $row['assemblyS'],
                'assemblyF' => $row['assemblyF'],
                //SET BUTTON BACKGROUND COLOR
                'assemblyS' => ($startBtnColor != NULL) ? "green" : "white",
                //ALTERNATE ROW COLOR
                'class1' => (!$x++%2) ? "backgroundColor1" : "backgroundColor2"
            );
            $rowCount++;
        }
    }
    $query->close();
}
$connection->close();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

If you `POST` to this, it will update the database. If you run `GET` to this, you will get the JSON data as a result.

This allows you to keep all your JavaScript within you HTML. This makes things a lot easier to troubleshoot too. It also allows you to call for data at any point. Just use `$.getJSON()` to pull the data.

MySQLi offers [prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) which I strongly suggest using. This will help protect again SQL Injection attempts. Your current code is vulnerable to these attacks.

Your data will come back as an array of objects. Similar to:

```
[{
  'jobID': 1,
  'jobName': "job1",
  'woodType': "hardwood",
  'finishColor': "cherry",
  'roomID': "room1",
  'assemblyS': "2017-06-30 09:00:00",
  'assemblyF': "2017-06-30 16:00:00",
  'startBtnColor': "green",
  'class1': "backgroundColor1"
}, {
  'jobID': 2,
  'jobName': "job1",
  'woodType': "hardwood",
  'finishColor': "cherry",
  'roomID': "room2",
  'assemblyS': "2017-07-01 09:00:00",
  'assemblyF': "2017-07-01 16:00:00",
  'startBtnColor': "green",
  'class1': "backgroundColor2"
}, {
  'jobID': 3,
  'jobName': "job1",
  'woodType': "hardwood",
  'finishColor': "cherry",
  'roomID': "room3",
  'assemblyS': "2017-07-02 09:00:00",
  'assemblyF': "2017-07-02 16:00:00",
  'startBtnColor': "green",
  'class1': "backgroundColor1"
}];
```

I would advise using `$.each()` to iterate over the data. You can build your table off this like so:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wkt9jnrq/

**HTML**

```
<table id="startJobs">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="rowStart">Start</th>
      <th class="rowJobName">Job Name</th>
      <th class="rowWoodType">Wood Type</th>
      <th class="rowFinishColor">Finish Color</th>
      <th class="rowComplete">Complete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  $.each(myData, function(k, o) {
    var btn = $("<button>", {
        id: "start-" + o.jobID
      })
      .css("background-color", o.startBtnColor)
      .html("Start")
      .click(function(e) {
        $.post("assemblyStartHandlerCopy.php", {
          jobID: o.jobID,
          roomID: o.roomID,
          finishColor: o.finishColor,
          startTime: o.assemblyS
        }, function(result) {
          if (result.length) {
            alert(result);
          }
        });
      });
    var row = $("<tr>").appendTo("#startJobs tbody");
    row.append($("<td>", {
        class: "rowStart " + o.class1
      }).append(btn),
      $("<td>", {
        class: "rowJobName " + o.class1
      }).html(o.jobName),
      $("<td>", {
        class: "rowWoodType " + o.class1
      }).html(o.woodType),
      $("<td>", {
        class: "rowFinishColor " + o.class1
      }).html(o.finishColor),
      $("<td>", {
        class: "rowComplete " + o.class1
      }).html(o.assemblyF));
  });
```

You can feed `$.each()` from within the `success` callback for `$.getJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a lot of things that you can improve in this code.

First, you should not write values from PHP to JavaScript directly, you should store them in variables and have separate file for JavaScript and use those variables instead.

Second, you should escape values before writing them to database to avoid possible SQL injections, using `addslashes` method.

What you are doing right now is writing all the code in one single file that's making code hard to understand. Organize your code and divide it in manageable chunks using methods/functions and have separate files where required.

Comment: Care to add some examples?

Comment: Note that the 'addslashes' method isn't going to be enough. You should use prepared statements or mysqli_real_escape_string with a configured charset.

Comment: Thanks for the addition @Nathan